# SELECT and INSERT into another table's field

Tags: mysql, select

Is this valid?

`SELECT COUNT(*) INTO mydb.table.field FROM sometable WHERE points=30;`

If it's not.. anybody who can tell me a similar solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No,
yours would be exactly like this one

```
INSERT INTO mydb.table (field)
SELECT Count(*)
FROM   sometable
WHERE  points=30;
```

Another example with more columns

```
INSERT INTO mydb.table (Col1, Col2, Col3)
SELECT Col1, Col2, Count(*)
FROM   sometable
WHERE  points=30;
```

[Here](http://www.brightcherry.co.uk/scribbles/mysql-insert-select-example/) you can find many examples.

Comment: Lol, I know, I did it like that right after I posted this stupid question....
`
SET @s='UPDATE `games` 
    SET ? = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
       FROM `cards`
       WHERE ? = ?)
    WHERE `gamenumber` = (SELECT `gameNumber`
                FROM `cards`
             WHERE `UUID` = ?)';
  PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
  EXECUTE stmt USING @v6, @v4, @v3, @v1;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;`

Thank you for bothering to answer tho :)

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO myTable (field) VALUES 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sometable where points=30)
```